# Hello, two questions about sklearn.Pipeline with custom transformer for timeseries

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-3.7, pipeline, transformer-model

How should I to modify the code below to make it work:

<s>target, predicted = pipe.fit_predict(df)</s>

### EDIT:

```
target, predicted = pipe.fit_transform(df, df)
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
np.random.seed(1)

rows,cols = 100,1
data = np.random.randint(100, size = (rows,cols))
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='20min') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['num_orders'], index=tidx)
      


class MakeFeatures(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

def __init__(self, X, y = None, max_lag = None, rolling_mean_day = None, rolling_mean_month = None):
    self.X = X.resample('1H').sum()
    self.max_lag = max_lag
    self.rolling_mean_day = rolling_mean_day
    self.rolling_mean_month = rolling_mean_month
        
def fit(self, X, y = None):
    return self

def transform(self, X, y = None):
    data = pd.DataFrame(index = self.X.index)
    data['num_orders'] = self.X['num_orders']
    data['year'] = self.X.index.year
    data['month'] = self.X.index.month
    data['day'] = self.X.index.day
    data['dayofweek'] = self.X.index.dayofweek
    
    data['detrend'] = self.X.shift() - self.X
    
    if self.max_lag:
        for lag in range(1, self.max_lag + 1):
            data['lag_{}'.format(lag)] = data['detrend'].shift(lag)
    if self.rolling_mean_day:
        data['rolling_mean_24'] = data.detrend.shift().rolling(self.rolling_mean_day).mean()
    
    if self.rolling_mean_month:
        data['rolling_mean_24'] = data['detrend'].shift().rolling(self.rolling_mean_month).mean()
    
    if data['year'].mean() == data['year'][1]:
        data = data.drop('year', axis = 1)
    
    data = data.dropna()
    
    y = data.num_orders
    data = data.drop('num_orders', 1)
    
    return data, y

pipe = Pipeline([
                ('features', MakeFeatures(df, df, 2 , 24)),
                ('scaler', StandardScaler())  
    ])

target, predicted = pipe.fit_transform(df, df)  # where ‘Target’ is y - the output from the Class
```

Out:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (9,7) into shape (9).
```

Each function inside the Pipeline is working fine.

I can run **MakeFeatures(df, df)** and **StandardScaler().fit_transform(df, df)** without a problem.

I can insert the product of MakeFeatures(df,df) into the StandardScaler and it has no mistake.

Comment: Hi, your current question is difficult to understand. Can you provide a sample/dummy of your data so that it can be tested with your code?

Comment: @Kim Tang, Thank you for your comment. At least now I'm understand where all the minuses are coming from. This is my first question and I still learn how to ask.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow then! Have a look at the tour over here https://stackoverflow.com/tour and then update your question with a "minimal reproducible example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code to reproduce your issue, so that others can help you better.

Comment: Let’s see if this going to work. Thank you for guiding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use

> target, predicted = pipe.fit_predict(df)

with your defined pipeline, because the fit_predict() method can only be used, if the estimator has such a method implemented as well. [Reference in documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit_predict)

> Valid only if the final estimator implements fit_predict.

Also, it would only return the predictions, so you can not use `target,predicted =` but should use `predicted =`

You got the error

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

because you are providing the `StandardScaler()` a `pandas.TimeSeries`.

This is because with your method call `pipe.fit_predict(df)` you only provide an 'X' and not an 'y' to the pipeline. This is fine for your first component of the pipeline "MakeFeatures" since it accepts an 'X' and returns 'data' and 'y', but in the pipeline the 'y' will not be used, because the 'y' has to be defined in the beginning of the fit_predict() call.

Have a look at the documentation of the method here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit_predict

It states for the 'y' parameter

> Training targets. Must fulfill label requirements for all steps of the
> pipeline.

So that 'y' would be used as the 'y' for all parts of the pipeline, but yours is not defined, so `None`.

What basically happens with your current pipeline is therefore this:

```
makeF = MakeFeatures(df, 2 , 24)
transformed_df = makeF.fit_transform(df)

sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(transformed_df)
```

and causes `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

So I suggest you to update your code like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

np.random.seed(1)

rows,cols = 100,1
data = np.random.randint(100, size = (rows,cols))
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='20min') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['num_orders'], index=tidx)
      
class MakeFeatures(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

  def __init__(self, X, max_lag = None, rolling_mean_day = None, rolling_mean_month = None):
      self.X = X.resample('1H').sum()
      self.max_lag = max_lag
      self.rolling_mean_day = rolling_mean_day
      self.rolling_mean_month = rolling_mean_month
          
  def fit(self, X):
      return self

  def transform(self, X):
      data = pd.DataFrame(index = self.X.index)
      data['num_orders'] = self.X['num_orders']
      data['year'] = self.X.index.year
      data['month'] = self.X.index.month
      data['day'] = self.X.index.day
      data['dayofweek'] = self.X.index.dayofweek
      
      data['detrend'] = self.X.shift() - self.X
      
      if self.max_lag:
          for lag in range(1, self.max_lag + 1):
              data['lag_{}'.format(lag)] = data['detrend'].shift(lag)
      if self.rolling_mean_day:
          data['rolling_mean_24'] = data.detrend.shift().rolling(self.rolling_mean_day).mean()
      
      if self.rolling_mean_month:
          data['rolling_mean_24'] = data['detrend'].shift().rolling(self.rolling_mean_month).mean()
      
      if data['year'].mean() == data['year'][1]:
          data = data.drop('year', axis = 1)
      
      data = data.dropna()
      
      y = data.num_orders
      data = data.drop('num_orders', 1)
      
      return data, list(y)

pipe = Pipeline([
                 ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                ('Model' , LinearRegression())
      ])

makeF = MakeFeatures(df, 2 , 24)
makeF.fit(df)
data,y = makeF.transform(df)
pipe.fit(data,y)  # where ‘Target’ is y - the output from the Class
```

Then you can use your pipeline to predict your data and evaluate the performance for instance with the r2_score:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

predictions = pipe.predict(data)
r2_score(y,predictions)
```

Comment: Kim Tang, thank you for the answer, but both StandardScaler and Pipeline accept the label parameter, so why it still not working if I modify my Class as _**MakeFeature(self, X, y,..)**_ and then call for **pipe.fit_transform(df,df) (where pipe = Pipeline([ ('features', MakeFeatures(df,df), ('scaler', StandardScaler())])** ?

Comment: I don't see your complete updated code here, but by looking at this, I think the error is that the StandardScaler will be called with the 'df' as the 'y' parameter, since you call the pipe.fit_transform(df,df). But the StandardScaler can not use the 'df' as 'y'.

Comment: first- thank you for your patient, not sure about the policy but my question is different from the main one which you have answered already. **StandardScaler().fit_transform(df,df)** works fine, **MakeFeatures(df,df)** works too. But  together: **pipe = Pipeline([ ('features', MakeFeatures(df,df), ('scaler', StandardScaler())]), pipe.fit_transform(df,df)** it doesn't work

Comment: Okay, just open up a new question with your problem, including the code and some data to reproduce and understand your problem. That way also others can help you too.